# Writing a bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I need to write a simple bash script called finduser, where classlist is the name of the classlist file, and username is a particular student's username, either first name or last time.
./finduser classlist username

The script should

- check that the correct number of arguments was received and print an error message if not,
- check whether the classlist file exists and print an error message if not,
- print the line of the given username in the classlist file

This is what I have so far but I am stuck!

```
#!/bin/bash
# check the correct number of arguments was received an print an error message if not
read classlist
echo "There are $# arguments"

# Check if the classlist file exusts and print error message if not
echo "checking if file exists"
        classlist=./classlist.txt
        if [ -f $classlist ]
        then
                 echo "$classlist exists."
        else echo "$classlist does not exist
        fi

# print the line of the given username

grep $2 $1
```

This is the text file

```
Alexander, Amy Elizabeth          BS      BADM          ACCT
Ayers, Brittany Nicole            BS      BADM          ACCT
Brown, Lyeshea Semondre Shayron   BS      BADM          ACCT
Calloway, Logan Mackenzie         BS      BADM          ACCT
Childers, Jamie Leigh             BS      BADM          ACCT
```

Comment: Each question should be about one specific technical problem that prevented you from finishing your script on your own. Don't ask us to just do your work for you.

Comment: See also [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/14122) on [meta].

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Users here expect you to have done the impossible before posting.  Ex. you have syntax issues.  Put your code in site https://www.shellcheck.net/ to see what they are, with solutions (ex. missing double quote on an `echo`).  Then read a bit on arguments.  You do not need `read`.  Also why assign a value to  variable classlist?  That is received in argument, so do not force its value in the code.

Comment: Error message belong on stderr: `echo "error message" >&2`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this

```
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage:"
    echo "    $0 {filename} {username}"
    exit 1
fi

filename="$1"
username="$2"

if [ ! -f "${filename}" ]; then
    echo "Error: file ${filename} not found"
    exit 1
fi

grep "$username" "$filename"
```

Output for error handling:

```
$ ./stackoverflow.sh  in.cvs Leigh
Usage:
    ./stackoverflow.sh {filename} {username}

$ ./stackoverflow.sh  in2.cvs Le
Error: file in2.cvs not found
```

Output for success:

```
$ ./stackoverflow.sh  in.cvs Leigh
Childers, Jamie Leigh             BS      BADM          ACCT
```